# NextJS routing by subdomain

Tags: next.js, static-site, aws-amplify

I'm using NextJS to build a website. There are 150 static webpages (SSG) generated at build time from infrequently changing JSON data.

Currently the webpages are at https://mywebsite.com/slug (and [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)) where "slug" is a unique 5 letter value.

I've been asked to make "slug" the subdomain, so "slug.mywebsite.com/" will resolve to the SSG page formerly at [www.mywebsite.com/slug](http://www.mywebsite.com/slug).

My initial and primary concern is figuring out if this is possible in NextJS and how routing would work. Does anyone have pointers or advice?

I assume adding/removing subdomains will involve changes to the build config and adding/removing pages should be infrequent enough that it may be OK if this bit isn't automated from the JSON file.

I'm deploying the site via AWS Amplify and prefer to remain on AWS; but could potentially move to Vercel or another hosting environment as we haven't launched yet. AWS has a 50 subdomain limit; so I've requested a quota increase. I see Vercel has a 50 domain limit, but not sure about subdomains.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes...kinda. But adding a new sub-domain will involve re-build of the Next.js app. Ref: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-multi-domain-locale/blob/main/next.config.js

Comment: Thanks @PsyGik. I'm checking if we're allowed to rewrite the url. If we are, that link looks promising.